# Is there a way to loop over folder with scandir? I'm facing a problem when looping

Tags: php, html

First I declared the variables to get the folders, and get the files into an array. See below

```
  $DOCROOT = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
  $dir    = $DOCROOT . '/php/pagamentos/resources/pagamentos';
  echo ($dir);
  $folder = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('.', '..'));
```

And I have the following array to loop:

```
array(4) {
  [2]=>
  string(33) "BMEPS_out22002508200201095005.txt"
  [3]=>
  string(33) "BMEPS_out22002508200204112009.txt"
  [4]=>
  string(33) "BMEPS_out22002508200204125012.txt"
  [5]=>
  string(33) "BMEPS_out22002508200205063000.txt"
}
```

Then I start looping the array with the following code

```
foreach ($folder as $file) {

    $fp = fopen($file, "r") or die("Unable to open file!");

    echo $file;


    fclose($fp);
}
```

But After all that I get the following error:

```
Warning: fopen(BMEPS_out22002508200204112009.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/php/pagamentos/index.php on line 40
Unable to open file!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a full path to the file. When you scan a dir you use `$dir = $DOCROOT . '/php/pagamentos/resources/pagamentos';` but when you call fopen you just use a file name. You have to provide a full path instead. For example:

```
foreach ($folder as $file) {
    $fullPath = $DOCROOT . '/php/pagamentos/resources/pagamentos/' . $file;
    //or
    $fullPath = $dir . '/' . $file;
    //now you use $fullPath instead just $file
}
```

In situation when you call just a file name the script tries to open a file in the same dir where execution of the script takes a place.

Comment: Thank you! You made my day. I don't know how I missed that.